# Join 2 tables with ID using createCriteria()

Tags: hibernate, grails, createcriteria

I have 2 tables p, q I am trying to join it with ID. using createAlias inside createCriteria.list()

Please show me right syntax for the join.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this up. Look for alias

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection